# Is salt an antihistamine?

Tags: nutrition

According to [Dr. F. Batmanghelidj](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fereydoon_Batmanghelidj) (as described [here](http://www.watercure2.org/histamines.htm)), salt effectively acts as an antihistamine, by suppressing the release of histamines.

> The best natural antihistamine is salt, according to Dr. Batmanghelidj If we take too much water and don't take enough salt for our water intake, the body will release histamine.

I see this claim repeated all over the web.

Is there any scientific basis to this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

On the contrary, several studies say that increasing salt intake increases the reactivity of the body to histamine, and may worsen asthma:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1833904/?page=1

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1679339/?page=1

Although another study questioned this:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC475179/

But no one actually says that salt prevents the release of histamines.

Comment: Please include any relevant conclusions as cites: this prevents link rot.